# Ext JS grid in a headless browser

Tags: extjs, wkhtmltopdf

I need to distribute a view/grid and its data as a PDF. My current plan is to render this in an HTML file inside a headless browser (wktohtmlpdf).

My problem is that the grid is not sized properly when it is rendered by the headless browser. When I specify a fixed width and height the grid does appear.

How do I make the grid stretch the entire HTML body so that it is print/PDF friendly?

Or maybe how do I setup the headless browser to display the grid in that way?

**Update:**

I tried with headless chrome and it has no issue rendering the grid without hardcoding dimensions. So this seems to be a wkhtmltopdf (config) issue.

Answer (score 1):

did you tried layout

```
layout: {
type:'vbox',
align: 'stretch'
}
```

Comment: The document hierarchy so far is body > grid. Applying a layout on the grid would only affect its children. So, I wrapped the grid inside a viewport with the layout config above: and it did not work still.

Comment: try making it like this
body->container-grid and on container apply layout as stretch

Comment: can you pls share the working fiddle reproducing the mentioned behaviour

Comment: Here is how it looks like https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/31mk.
I cannot reproduce this issue with fiddle, I need to run/render this application inside wkhtmltopdf which will produce a pdf version